# show notifications of new e-mails without displaying the content

Tags: ios, notifications, gmail

When my iPad is locked, you can still read notifications of new e-mails. the app in question is gmail. for privacy reasons I wish that with the iPad blocked you could not read the content of the e-mails, but only show notifications of new e-mails without displaying the contents.

Answer (score 8):

Go to Settings → Notifications → *app name* (e.g. Gmail) → Show Previews and change  the setting from ‘Always’ to ‘When Unlocked’.